# JSDOM - Hardcore way - Add external script and use it

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I'm starting to use JSDOM and I have this working properly:

```
jsdom.env(
'<p><a class="the-link" href="https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom">jsdom\'s Homepage</a></p>',
["http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/test.js"],
function (errors, window) {
    //console.log("contents of a.the-link:", window.$("a.the-link").text());
    console.log(errors);
    console.log(window.myVar);
    console.log(window.test);

});
```

Test.js script is very simple:

```
console.log("testing testing testing");
window.myVar = "myVar Content";
var test = "test content";
```

The content of myVar and test is displayed when I execute the script.

But the problem is when I start to do it on the hardcore way (hardcore as the documentation say):

I do the follow:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var document = jsdom("<html><head></head><body>hello world</body></html>");
var window = document.parentWindow;

var script =  document.createElement("SCRIPT");
script.src = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/test.js";
var head= window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
var window = document.parentWindow;

console.log("myVar Content: " + window.myVar);
```

In this case, window.myVar is undefined.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found how to do it:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var document = jsdom("<html><head></head><body>hello world</body></html>");
var window = document.parentWindow;

var script =  document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
var fs = require("fs");
var requireJSFile = fs.readFileSync("test.js","utf8");
    script.innerHTML = requireJSFile;
var head= window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(script);
var window = document.parentWindow;

console.log(document.innerHTML);
console.log("myVar Content: " + window.myVar);
```

I will add a function in the var and I will see if I can use it as: window.myVar(param1, param2, param3).

I'm pretty sure it will work.